# Cakephp add form inside modal window while in index view

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

New to cakephp here.. wondering how i could have a button whilst in my index view to open an add form ( for the same model ). once i submit this form i'd like the modal to disappear and the new record to be show in the index view. I was thinking of putting the add form in a cake element? but not sure how to put this in a modal window. any advice would be great thanks.

Answer (score 4):

What @savedario says makes perfect sense. I [blogged](https://learntech.imsu.ox.ac.uk/blog/?p=897) about this just before Christmas and have copied the relevant bits below:

View/Users/index.php:

```
<!-- overlayed element -->
   <div id="dialogModal">
     <!-- the external content is loaded inside this tag -->
     <div class="contentWrap"></div>
   </div>
...
<div class="actions">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Add user', true), array("controller"=>"users", "action"=>"add"), array("class"=>"overlay", "title"=>"Add User"));
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
...
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    //prepare the dialog
    $( "#dialogModal" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        show: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 500
            },
        hide: {
            effect: "blind",
            duration: 500
            },
        modal: true
        });
    //respond to click event on anything with 'overlay' class
    $(".overlay").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#contentWrap').load($(this).attr("href"));  //load content from href of link
        $('#dialogModal').dialog('option', 'title', $(this).attr("title"));  //make dialog title that of link
        $('#dialogModal').dialog('open');  //open the dialog
        });
    });
</script>
```

Views/Users/add.ctp:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User');
echo $this->Form->input('name');
echo $this->Js->submit('Save', array(  //create 'ajax' save button
    'update' => '#contentWrap'  //id of DOM element to update with selector
    ));
if (false != $saved){ //will only be true if saved OK in controller from ajax save above
    echo "<script>
        $('#dialogModal').dialog('close');  //close containing dialog         
        location.reload();  //if you want to reload parent page to show updated user
    </script>";
    }
echo $this->Form->end();
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(); //assuming this view is rendered without the default layout, make sure you write out the JS buffer at the bottom of the page
```

Controllers/UsersController.php:

```
function add() {
    ...
    $this->set('saved', false); //false by default - controls closure of overlay in which this is opened
    if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
        $this->User->create();
        if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)){ 
            $this->set('saved', true); //only set true if data saves OK
            } 
        }
    ...
    }
```

You'll need to have included JQuery 1.9+ and JQuery UI js files in the layout used by your index.ctp and add.ctp.

Actually I have now switched to Bootstrap modals in my own code because I think they look nicer but the approach is very similar.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer really appreciate it. i came up with my solution last night, simply by adding an element in index view that opens a bootstrap modal that contains the add form.

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply, i came up with a similar solution last night before reading this. a bootstrap modal window including the button to open it inside a cake element. i then have the add project form inside the modal window and using the $this->js->submit function to send the data to the server. when the modal window closes the new record is in the index view. is this bad use of MCV? i call the bootstrap element from the index view.

Comment: I suppose what I'm confused by is why it needs to be in an element at all, unless you are reusing it in other places?

Comment: How did you solve the problem of returning to the dialog when the Model does not validate ?
I can't seem to find it.

Comment: It does it automagically if you load the form from the add action as shown above.

Answer (score 3):

CakePHP does not have a built-in functionality to do what you want.
Using Elements here does not necessarily help, unless you find yourself writing the same code in different places...

I could not find anything already written to handle this, so I wrote my own javascript functions that work but I doubt could be used as a plugin.
To explain the whole thing would be a bit too long here.

I suggest you start looking at [Jquery UI Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/).
Your index view will need an 'onclick' on the 'add' action button to open the dialog.
The content of the dialog itself could come from the same add() action you would normally use, loaded via an ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

I used bootstrap 3 for my cakephp project which included modals, but that may be overkill for your project.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use bootstrap or jquery to do this. CakePHP does not have a built-in functionality to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Typo

```
<div class="contentWrap"></div>
```

must be

```
<div id="contentWrap"></div>
```

or

```
$('#contentWrap').load($(this).attr("href"));
```

must be

```
$('.contentWrap').load($(this).attr("href"));
```